# question of definition pseudospectrum

Tags: linear-algebra

The pseudospectrum of a square matrix A is defined as
$$\Lambda_\epsilon(A) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | \left \| (z I - A)^{-1} \right \| > \epsilon^{-1} \} $$
An alternative definition is 
$$\Lambda_\epsilon(A)_1 = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | z \mbox{ is eigenvalue of } A+E,  \left \| E \right \| \leq \epsilon\} $$
I want to prove that both definitions are equal. I managed to prove that $ \Lambda_\epsilon(A)_1 \subset \Lambda_\epsilon(A)$ but I can't prove the opposite. In fact, I don't have an idea to tackle this problem. Can someone help me?

kind regards

Comment: Are you sure that it is not $\frac1\epsilon$ in the first definition?

Comment: you're right. I adapt it

Comment: [Trefethen and Embree](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/pseudospectra/) have a whole website dedicated to pseudospectra. They are also the authors of a book on the topic. They surely know, try looking on the website

Comment: Ok, I found the proof, thanks